# Highlight current bash prompt line

Tags: bash, prompt

I want the terminal to highlight the current **bash prompt** line.
The effect I'm trying to acheive is the same as in text editors where the current line with the cursor is highlighted.
Something like this:
[image]

Comment: It's conceivable that your *shell* could support some customization like this, but it's irrelevant to the choice of terminal.

Comment: This depends on the shell, not on the terminal. Given the appearance of your prompt, I presume you use bash. Please edit your question if this is not the case.

Comment: oh ok sorry, kinda new to stackexchange and forgot the rules

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy with highlighting *only the prompt*, then the following will apply reverse colors on whatever you have already in `PS1`:

```
PS1="\[\e[7m\]$PS1\[\e(B\e[m\]"
```

If you have a space at the end of the prompt (this is common practice) that you don't want to highlight:

```
PS1="[\e[7m]${PS1::-1}[\e(B\e[m] "
```

Some terminals, at least iTerm for macOS, have the option to set a "cursor guide". This is probably doing *exactly* what you want to achieve (I have exaggerated the guide in the picture, I usually have it much more transparent, and red, as in the second picture):

[image: iTerm with green transparent cursor guide, running bash]

The cursor guide has nothing to do with the shell and will be *always* be displayed, regardless of what you're doing (very faint red cursor guide on the line reading `AC_CONF_AUX_DIR([build])`, here shown in the `vim` editor):

[image: iTerm with faint red cursor guide, running vim]

Unfortunately I only run iTerm on macOS, so I don't know if there are terminal emulators out there that can do this for your particular Unix.

Comment: PS1="\[\e[7m\]${PS1::-1}\[\e(B\e[m\] " Just to get rid of that extra highlighted space at the end.

Comment: @auselen Thanks. Finally got around to add that in.